# Varying execution time of for loop in Java

Tags: java, optimization, for-loop

I am a newbie in Java. I have done following coding.

```
class TimeComplex{
    public static void main(String []args){
        long startTime, stopTime, elapsedTime;

        //first call
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\nstart time : " + startTime + "\n");
        calcForLoop();
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stop time : " + stopTime + "\n");
        elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\t1st loop execution time : " + elapsedTime+ "\n");

        //second call
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("start time : " + startTime + "\n");
        calcForLoop();
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stop time : " + stopTime + "\n");
        elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\t2nd loop execution time : " + elapsedTime + "\n");

        //third call
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("start time : " + startTime + "\n");
        calcForLoop();
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stop time : " + stopTime + "\n");
        elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\t3rd loop execution time : " + elapsedTime + "\n");
    }

    static void calcForLoop(){
        for(long i = 12_85_47_75_807L; i > 0; i--);
    }
}
```

The code runs a for-loop for a long period of time just to increase the execution time of the program. When the `calcForLoop()` is called for the first time the execution time of the program is maximum when the same method is called for the second time the program takes lesser time than the first call and the third call to the method `calcForLoop()` is less than or equal to the second execution time. I ran this program for 5-6 times and the I got the same pattern of execution time. [image: This is the output of my program.]

My question is why does this happen when the code to execute remains same for all the three time. Is there any code optimization that takes place by the compiler or it is dependent on the operating system environment. What sort of optimization is done by compiler when there is repeated execution of the same block of code like in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JIT (just in time) compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiles code that the JVM detects is being executed a lot, which accounts for the increase in performance. There may actually be a brief *reduction* in performance while such compilation is taking place.

It is usual to allow for this effect in performance testing - you execute the code a few thousand times, then start your benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Loop nest optimization is an optimization technique that applies a set of loop transformations for the purpose of locality optimization or parallelization. One classical usage is to **reduce memory access latency or the cache bandwidth** necessary due to cache reuse for some common linear algebra algorithms.

Comment: Can you make the explanation easier. What is loop nest optimization and cache bandwidth??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more accurate in measuring the elapsed time you must use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead of using [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

And of course what Bohemian mentioned about JIT do comes into picture.